# How to send multiple complex signals to the same thread over time?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, parameter-passing, qt-signals

I am writing a GUI using PyQT5.10 on Spyder3.8.  The user enters several parameters, including strings, integers, and floats, and presses the " Send params/start thread " button.  This starts a new thread where the parameters are stored, and a function makes calculations. The thread is supposed to pick up these parameters from the GUI right away, but in addition to this the GUI has buttons which can edit parameters or send new parameters to the thread, hopefully updating them in real time.
My question: is it possible to send all of these int/str/float parameters to the same thread using signals/slots at different times? Is there a particular strategy which would be best? I haven’t found similar examples online, but I believe this could have widespread application for Python users in many fields.
I've included a scaled-down version of a script below which makes the GUI and is able to start a new thread but can’t pass the initial variables list to the running thread.  I’ve tried different strategies, nothing worked so far.  The current script doesn’t have the function buttons set up to edit thread variables in real time as this generated an error.  I would like to discuss the particulars of passing variables into running threads, however my main question remains “is this possible?”

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog, 
        QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton,   
        QSpinBox, QStyleFactory, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import logging
import logging.handlers


# threadpool = QThreadPool()
# print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % threadpool.maxThreadCount()) 
thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
print('Intro thread ID: ',thread_id)

def trap_exc_during_debug(*args):
    print('debug arg:',args)
sys.excepthook = trap_exc_during_debug


# This class sets up the thread
class Worker(QObject):
    print('begin ThreadClass')
    sig_msg = pyqtSignal(str)  

    @pyqtSlot(float,float,int,str)
    def __init__(self,param1,param2,param3,param4,parent = None):
        #print('params in Worker init: ',param1,param2,param3,param4)
        self.p1=param1; self.p2=param2; self.p3=param3; self.p4=param4
        print('params in Worker init: ',self.p1,self.p2,self.p3,self.p4)
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('Worker __Init__ thread ID: ',thread_id)
        self.__id = 1
        self.__abort = False
        self.__reset = False
        print('end Worker init')

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):  # This function is what will happen in the thread when it starts
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('work thread ID: ',thread_id)
        print('params in work fcn: ',self.p1,self.p2,self.p3,self.p4)
        p1=self.p1
        p2=self.p2
        p3=self.p3
        p4=self.p4
        print('params in work fcn: ',p1,p2,p3,p4)
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('work thread ID: ',thread_id)

        # app.processEvents()     # This approach generated a TypeError: 
        #     if fn==1:           #("work() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fn'
        #     p1-=1
        #     print('New param1 value in thread: ',p1)
        #     thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        #     print('fcn1b thread ID: ',thread_id)
        # elif fn==2:
        #     p2+=1
        #     print('New param2 value in thread: ',p2)
        #     thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        #     print('fcn2b thread ID: ',thread_id)
        # elif fn==3:
        #     p3+=1
        #     print('New param3 value in thread: ',p3)
        #     thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        #     print('fcn1b thread ID: ',thread_id)
        # elif fn==4:
        #     p4=param4
        #     print('New param4 value in thread: ',p4)
        #     thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        #     print('fcn1b thread ID: ',thread_id)


    @pyqtSlot(float)
    def fcn1b(self,prm1):
        print('New fcn1 value in thread: ',prm1)
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('fcn1b thread ID: ',thread_id)

    @pyqtSlot(float)
    def fcn2b(self,prm2):
        print('New fcn2 value in thread: ',prm2)
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('fcn2b thread ID: ',thread_id)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def fcn3b(self,prm3):
        print('New fcn3 value in thread: ',prm3)
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('fcn3b thread ID: ',thread_id)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def fcn4b(self,prm4):
        print('New fcn4 value in thread: ',prm4)
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('fcn4b thread ID: ',thread_id)


#This class creates the GUI, sets up the buttons, starts new thread, allows parameter edits after thread start.
#Parameter edits are seen in GUI and are supposed to be sent to thread also. 
class WidgetGallery(QDialog): 
    sendinitialparams = pyqtSignal(float,float,int,str)
    sendparameter1 = pyqtSignal(float)
    sendparameter2 = pyqtSignal(float)
    sendparameter3 = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendparameter4 = pyqtSignal(str)
    NUM_THREADS = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super(WidgetGallery, self).__init__()
        self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()
        styleComboBox = QComboBox()
        styleComboBox.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        self.createTopLeftGroupBox()
        self.createTopRightGroupBox()
        self.createbottomRightGroupBox()
        topLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topLeftGroupBox, 2, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topRightGroupBox, 2, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightGroupBox, 3, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")        

    def createTopLeftGroupBox(self):
        self.topLeftGroupBox = QGroupBox("Settings")
        l1= QLabel("Param1 Value:")
        self.DoubleSpinBox1 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMinimum(0)
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMaximum(99)        
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(20.5)   
        l2 = QLabel("Param2 Value:")  
        self.DoubleSpinBox2 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setMinimum(0)
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setMaximum(99)        
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setValue(10.5)   
        l3= QLabel("Param3 Value:")
        self.SpinBox1 = QSpinBox()
        self.SpinBox1.setMinimum(0)
        self.SpinBox1.setMaximum(99)
        self.SpinBox1.setValue(5)  
        l4 = QLabel("Param4 Value:")
        self.textEdit1 = QLineEdit('string1')

        layout = QGridLayout()      
        layout.addWidget(l1, 1,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.DoubleSpinBox1, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(l2, 2,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.DoubleSpinBox2, 2, 2, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(l3, 3,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.SpinBox1, 3, 2, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(l4, 4,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit1, 4, 2, 1, 2)        
        layout.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        self.topLeftGroupBox.setLayout(layout)   

    def createTopRightGroupBox(self):
        self.topRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Adjust")
        self.defaultPushButton0 = QPushButton("Send params/start thread")
        self.defaultPushButton0.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton0.pressed.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.defaultPushButton1 = QPushButton("Decrease Param1 in GUI/thread", self)  #  self?  # log
        self.defaultPushButton1.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton1.pressed.connect(self.func1)
        self.defaultPushButton2 = QPushButton("Increase Param2 in GUI/thread")
        self.defaultPushButton2.setDefault(False)     
        self.defaultPushButton2.pressed.connect(self.func2)
        self.defaultPushButton3 = QPushButton("Increase Param3 in GUI/thread")
        self.defaultPushButton3.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton3.pressed.connect(self.func3)
        self.defaultPushButton4 = QPushButton("Send new Param4 to GUI/thread")
        self.defaultPushButton4.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton4.pressed.connect(self.func4)
        self.defaultPushButton5 = QPushButton("Abort Worker")
        self.defaultPushButton5.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton5.pressed.connect(self.abort_workers)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton0)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton1)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton2)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton3)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton4)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton5)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.topRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createbottomRightGroupBox(self):
        self.bottomRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Log")
        self.log = QTextEdit()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.log)
        self.bottomRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def func1(self):
        param1=float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param1-=1
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(param1)
        self.sendparameter1.emit(param1)

    def func2(self):
        param2 = float(self.DoubleSpinBox2.value())
        param2+=1
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setValue(param2)
        self.sendparameter2.emit(param2)

    def func3(self):
        param3 = int(self.SpinBox1.value()) 
        param3+=1
        self.SpinBox1.setValue(param3)
        self.sendparameter3.emit(param3)

    def func4(self):
        param4=str(self.textEdit1.text())
        self.sendparameter4.emit(param4)

    def start_threads(self):
        self.log.append('starting {} thread'.format(self.NUM_THREADS))
        self.__workers_done = 0
        self.__threads = []
        worker = Worker(float,float,int,str)
        print('a')
        thread = QThread()
        thread.setObjectName('thread_1') 
        print('b')
        self.__threads.append((thread, worker))
        worker.moveToThread(thread)
        # get progress messages from worker:
        worker.sig_msg.connect(self.log.append)
        # get ready to start worker:
        receiving_class = Worker(float,float,int,str)
        print('c')
        thread.started.connect(worker.work)
        #thread.start()  
        print('d')
        param1=float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param2 = float(self.DoubleSpinBox2.value())
        param3 = int(self.SpinBox1.value())
        param4 = str(self.textEdit1.text())
        #time.sleep(.0001) # .01 # .005 # .001
        print('Transfer data to Worker init')
        self.sendinitialparams.emit(param1,param2,param3,param4)
        thread.start()
        print('End of start_threads')

    @pyqtSlot()
    def abort_workers(self):
        for thread, worker in self.__threads:
            print(thread)
        thread.quit()  
        thread.wait()  
        self.log.append('Thread exited')
        print('Thread quit')


# This class coordinates many of the above classes and functions.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('1')
    app = QApplication([])
    WG = WidgetGallery()
    WG.show()
    print('2')
    receiving_class = Worker(float,float,int,str)
    print('3')
    WG.sendinitialparams.connect(receiving_class.__init__) # work # __init__
    WG.sendparameter1.connect(receiving_class.fcn1b)
    WG.sendparameter2.connect(receiving_class.fcn2b)
    WG.sendparameter3.connect(receiving_class.fcn3b)
    WG.sendparameter4.connect(receiving_class.fcn4b)
    print('4')  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to send signals across threads at any time you want to. What kind of errors did you get?
Here is an example.

```
import time
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class WorkerThread(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = self.base_int = 0
        self.stop_signal = False
        self.progress = 0

        class Signals(QObject):
            count = pyqtSignal(int)
            base_int = pyqtSignal(int)
            stop_signal = pyqtSignal(bool)

        self.signals = Signals()
        self.signals.count.connect(partial(setattr, self, 'count'))
        self.signals.base_int.connect(partial(setattr, self, 'base_int'))
        self.signals.stop_signal.connect(partial(setattr, self, 'stop_signal'))

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_signal:
            print('worker - count:', self.count)
            self.progress += self.base_int
            print('worker - working hard:', self.progress)
            time.sleep(1)
        print('worker - end')

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")
        widget = QWidget()
        central_layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.count = 0
        self.base_int_input = QSpinBox()
        central_layout.addWidget(self.base_int_input)
        self.send_signals_button = QPushButton('send_signals')
        self.send_signals_button.clicked.connect(self.send_signals)
        self.stop_button = QPushButton('stop')
        central_layout.addWidget(self.send_signals_button)
        central_layout.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 180)

        self.worker_thread = WorkerThread()
        thread_pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        thread_pool.start(self.worker_thread)

        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(partial(
            self.worker_thread.signals.stop_signal.emit, True))


    def send_signals(self):
        self.worker_thread.signals.count.emit(self.count)
        self.worker_thread.signals.base_int.emit(
            self.base_int_input.value())
        self.count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I don't think if it is a good idea the work is calculation intensive because of python GIL. Why not do it in pure python? Just spawn a python process to do the calculation.

Edit on your example:

```
import sys; from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QThread, QObject,QRunnable
from PyQt5.QtCore import *; from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QLabel,
         QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QStyleFactory, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout)
import logging; import logging.handlers; from functools import partial; from PyQt5.Qt import *

thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
print('Intro thread ID: ',thread_id)

from queue import Queue, Empty as EmptyQueue

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.parameter_queue = Queue()

        class Signals(QObject):
            sendinitialparams = pyqtSignal(float)
            sendparameter1 = pyqtSignal(float)
        self.signals = Signals()
        self.signals.sendinitialparams.connect(self.parameter_queue.put)
        self.signals.sendparameter1.connect(self.parameter_queue.put)

    def run(self):
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        me = 'Worker ID-%d:' % thread_id
        print(me, 'begin work')
        while True:
            try:
                parameter = self.parameter_queue.get(timeout=10)
            except EmptyQueue:
                break
            print(me, 'input -', parameter)
            output = self.work_hard(parameter)
            print(me, 'output -', output)
        print(me, 'end work, goodbye')

    def work_hard(self, input):
        output = input
        return output



class WidgetGallery(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(WidgetGallery, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()
        styleComboBox = QComboBox()
        styleComboBox.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        self.createTopLeftGroupBox()
        self.createTopRightGroupBox()
        self.createbottomRightGroupBox()
        topLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topLeftGroupBox, 2, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topRightGroupBox, 2, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightGroupBox, 3, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")

    def createTopLeftGroupBox(self):
        self.topLeftGroupBox = QGroupBox("Settings")
        l1= QLabel("Param1 Value:")
        self.DoubleSpinBox1 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMinimum(0)
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMaximum(99)
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(20.5)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(l1, 1,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.DoubleSpinBox1, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        self.topLeftGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createTopRightGroupBox(self):
        self.topRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Adjust")
        self.defaultPushButton0 = QPushButton("Start thread")
        self.defaultPushButton0.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton0.pressed.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.defaultPushButton1 = QPushButton("Decrease Param1 in GUI/thread", self)
        self.defaultPushButton1.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton1.pressed.connect(self.func1)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton0)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton1)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.topRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createbottomRightGroupBox(self):
        self.bottomRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Log")
        self.log = QTextEdit()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.log)
        self.bottomRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def func1(self):
        param1=float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param1-=1
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(param1)
        #self.param1=param1
        #WG=WidgetGallery()

        # self.worker=Worker() <--- send to the same thread?

        print('self.DoubleSpinBox1.value()', self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        self.worker.signals.sendparameter1.emit(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())

    def start_threads(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
        thread_pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        thread_pool.start(self.worker)
        self.send_signals()
        print('End of start_threads')

    def send_signals(self):
        self.worker2=Worker()  # not started....so, no effect
        self.worker2.signals.sendparameter1.emit(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    WG = WidgetGallery()
    WG.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Still not able to pass variables into a thread.  I'm using 'self.worker2.signals.sendparameter1.emit(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())'                          to send a float value and                                                                                                     
'for b in args:          print('arg: ',b)'                                                                                                
to receive it (I've also included a Signals class, following ToSimplicity's template above).  There is no error, the problem is that nothing is getting sent.

Comment: maybe you can make an example with one worker and two different signals? that could be easier to identify the problem and communicate.

Comment: Example as per request has been provided.  It was pretty long so I posted it as an answer above.  Thanks

Comment: check the edit. if you'd like to add another thread, you need to start it and decide which thread you'd like to do which job.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Script is now working, I will include another example.

Answer (score 0):

The following successfully creates a GUI and thread but variables are not passed to thread.  Please hit Start Thread, then hit Decrease Param1 in GUI/Thread.

```
import sys; from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QThread, QObject,QRunnable
from PyQt5.QtCore import *; from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QLabel,
         QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QStyleFactory, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout)
import logging; import logging.handlers; from functools import partial; from PyQt5.Qt import *

thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
print('Intro thread ID: ',thread_id)

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        class Signals(QObject):
            sendinitialparams = pyqtSignal(float)
            sendparameter1 = pyqtSignal(float)
        self.signals = Signals()
        self.signals.sendinitialparams.connect(partial(setattr, self, 'sendinitialparams'))
        self.signals.sendparameter1.connect(partial(setattr, self, 'sendparameter1'))
        print('args in thread: ',*args)
        for b in args:
            print('arg: ',b)

    def run(self,*args,**kwargs): 
        print('begin work')   

        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('work thread ID: ',thread_id)

class WidgetGallery(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(WidgetGallery, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()
        styleComboBox = QComboBox()
        styleComboBox.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        self.createTopLeftGroupBox()
        self.createTopRightGroupBox()
        self.createbottomRightGroupBox()
        topLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topLeftGroupBox, 2, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topRightGroupBox, 2, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightGroupBox, 3, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")      

    def createTopLeftGroupBox(self):
        self.topLeftGroupBox = QGroupBox("Settings")
        l1= QLabel("Param1 Value:")
        self.DoubleSpinBox1 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMinimum(0)
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMaximum(99)        
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(20.5)   
        layout = QGridLayout()      
        layout.addWidget(l1, 1,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.DoubleSpinBox1, 1, 2, 1, 2)       
        layout.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        self.topLeftGroupBox.setLayout(layout)   

    def createTopRightGroupBox(self):
        self.topRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Adjust")
        self.defaultPushButton0 = QPushButton("Start thread")
        self.defaultPushButton0.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton0.pressed.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.defaultPushButton1 = QPushButton("Decrease Param1 in GUI/thread", self)
        self.defaultPushButton1.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton1.pressed.connect(self.func1)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton0)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton1)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.topRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createbottomRightGroupBox(self):
        self.bottomRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Log")
        self.log = QTextEdit()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.log)
        self.bottomRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def func1(self):
        param1=float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param1-=1
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(param1)
        #self.param1=param1
        #WG=WidgetGallery()
        self.worker=Worker()
        self.worker.signals.sendparameter1.emit(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())

    def start_threads(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
        thread = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        thread.start(self.worker)
        self.send_signals()       
        print('End of start_threads')

    def send_signals(self):
        self.worker2=Worker()
        self.worker2.signals.sendparameter1.emit(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    WG = WidgetGallery()
    WG.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Thread sets up properly and parameters are sent to thread as a list.
# User may then modify parameter values using buttons.

import sys; from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QThread, QObject,QRunnable
from PyQt5.QtCore import *; from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QLabel,
         QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QStyleFactory, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout)
import logging; import logging.handlers; from functools import partial; from PyQt5.Qt import *
from queue import Queue, Empty as EmptyQueue


thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
print('Intro thread ID: ',thread_id)

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.parameter_queue = Queue()
        self.parameter_queue2 = Queue()

        class Signals(QObject):
            sendinitialparams = pyqtSignal(list)
            sendparameter1 = pyqtSignal(str)
            sendparameter2 = pyqtSignal(str)

        self.signals = Signals()
        self.signals.sendinitialparams.connect(self.parameter_queue.put)
        self.signals.sendparameter1.connect(self.parameter_queue.put)
        self.signals.sendparameter2.connect(self.parameter_queue.put)

    def run(self):
        thread_id = int(QThread.currentThreadId())
        me = 'Worker ID-%d:' % thread_id
        print(me, 'begin work')

        x=0
        while x<10:
            parameter = self.parameter_queue.get()
            output = self.work_hard(parameter)
            if type(parameter)==list:
                print('parameters in run: ',parameter)
                p1=parameter[0]
                p2=parameter[1]
                print('p1 in run: ',p1)
                print('p2 in run: ',p2)
            elif type(parameter)==str:
                par=str(output)
                ff=int(par[0])
                if ff==1:
                    p1=float(par[1:])
                elif ff==2:
                    p2=float(par[1:])
                p0=str(', ')
                print('parameters in run (b): ',p1,p0,p2)
                ne = 'Worker ID-%d:' % thread_id
                print(ne)
                x+=1

        oe = 'Worker ID-%d:' % thread_id
        print(oe, 'end work, goodbye')

    def work_hard(self, input):
        output = input
        print('input: ',input)
        return output


class WidgetGallery(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WidgetGallery, self).__init__()
        self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()
        styleComboBox = QComboBox()
        styleComboBox.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        self.createTopLeftGroupBox()
        self.createTopRightGroupBox()
        self.createbottomRightGroupBox()
        topLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topLeftGroupBox, 2, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topRightGroupBox, 2, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightGroupBox, 3, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")

    def createTopLeftGroupBox(self):
        self.topLeftGroupBox = QGroupBox("Settings")
        l1= QLabel("Param1 Value:")
        self.DoubleSpinBox1 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMinimum(0)
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setMaximum(99)
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(20.5)
        l2= QLabel("Param2 Value:")
        self.DoubleSpinBox2 = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setMinimum(0)
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setMaximum(99)
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setValue(10.5)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(l1, 1,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.DoubleSpinBox1, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(l2, 2,0,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.DoubleSpinBox2, 2, 2, 1, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        self.topLeftGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createTopRightGroupBox(self):
        self.topRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Adjust")
        self.defaultPushButton0 = QPushButton("Start thread")
        self.defaultPushButton0.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton0.pressed.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.defaultPushButton1 = QPushButton("Decrease Param1 in GUI/thread", self)
        self.defaultPushButton1.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton1.pressed.connect(self.func1)
        self.defaultPushButton2 = QPushButton("Increase Param2 in GUI/thread", self)
        self.defaultPushButton2.setDefault(False)
        self.defaultPushButton2.pressed.connect(self.func2)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton0)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton1)
        layout.addWidget(self.defaultPushButton2)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.topRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createbottomRightGroupBox(self):
        self.bottomRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Log")
        self.log = QTextEdit()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.log)
        self.bottomRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def func1(self):
        param1=float(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        param1-=1
        self.DoubleSpinBox1.setValue(param1)
        ps1=str(self.DoubleSpinBox1.value())
        idps1='1'+ps1
        self.worker.signals.sendparameter1.emit(idps1)

    def func2(self):
        param2=float(self.DoubleSpinBox2.value())
        param2+=1
        self.DoubleSpinBox2.setValue(param2)
        ps2=str(self.DoubleSpinBox2.value())
        idps2='2'+ps2
        self.worker.signals.sendparameter2.emit(idps2)

    def start_threads(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
        thread_pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        thread_pool.start(self.worker)
        self.send_signals()
        print('End of start_threads')

    def send_signals(self):
        params=([self.DoubleSpinBox1.value(),self.DoubleSpinBox2.value()])
        self.worker.signals.sendinitialparams.emit(params)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    WG = WidgetGallery()
    WG.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```